# Better way to do employee Directory

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, people-picker, people-search

Right now I have a simple custom list with

```
username (People 
lastname (simple text
work# (text
Home# (text
alt email (text
```

I Just realized I could do

```
username (People 
Lastname (People Display Last
work (People display work number
Home (People display Home Number
alt email
```

but I still have to enter the persons for each row. Is there a way to just display a list of users (for example by security group

then list out

```
name
number
number
department
```

It seems silly that there isnt a better way to do this

Comment: That is what the user profile service, my site, and people search are for.

Comment: I do not see an option to add a people search page for this version of sharepoint (sharepoint online w/office365) can you point in the right direction?

Comment: In SPO do you have a Search site? Usually this is provisioned by default under: https://<tennant>.sharepoint.com/search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx

Comment: Search assumes I know who I am looking for. There is a difference between search and a Directory

Comment: Yes, but you have not told us what you are trying to do. Search for "*" and it will return everyone.

Comment: (Im trying to setup a directory) How do I set a link to default search *?

Comment: If you are using a Search Web Part set the query to "*". If you are building the UI yourself, with REST for example, use * as the initial query parameter and then refine from there.